# Boundedness of the inverse (Evans) why the chosen subsequence converge in $L^2(U)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, weak-convergence, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

> **THEOREM 6** (Boundedness of the inverse). If $\lambda \notin \Sigma$, there exists a constant $C$ such that
>
> $$
> \|u\|_{L^{2}(U)} \leq C\|f\|_{L^{2}(U)} \tag{29}
> $$
> whenever $f \in L^{2}(U)$ and $u \in H_{0}^{1}(U)$ is the unique weak solution of
> $$
> \left\{\begin{array}{c1}
> L u=\lambda u+f & \text { in } U \\
> u=0 & \text { on } \partial U
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> The constant $C$ depends only on $\lambda, U$ and the coefficients of $L .$
> This constant will blow up if $\lambda$ approaches an eigenvalue.
>
> *Proof.* If not, there would exist sequences $\left\{f_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \subset L^{2}(U)$ and $\left\{u_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \subset$ $H_{0}^{1}(U)$ such that
> $$
> \left\{\begin{aligned}
> L u_{k} &=\lambda u_{k}+f_{k} & & \text { in } U \\
> u_{k} &=0 & & \text { on } \partial U
> \end{aligned}\right.
> $$
> in the weak sense, but
> $$
> \left\|u_{k}\right\|_{L^{2}(U)}>k\left\|f_{k}\right\|_{L^{2}(U)} \quad(k=1, \ldots)
> $$
> As we may with no loss suppose $\left\|u_{k}\right\|_{L^{2}(U)}=1,$ we see $f_{k} \rightarrow 0$ in $L^{2}(U)$. **According to the usual energy estimates the sequence $\left\{u_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded in $H_{0}^{1}(U) .$** Thus there exists a subsequence $\left\{u_{k_j}\right\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ $\subset \left\{u_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that
> $$
> \left\{\begin{array}{c1}
> u_{k_j}&→u  & & \text {weakly in } H_{0}^{1}(U) \\
> u_{k_j} &→u & & \text {in } L^2(U)\\ \tag{30} \label{eq30}
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> (See §D.4 for weak convergence.)Then $u$ is a weak solution of
> $$
> \left\{\begin{array}{c1}
> L u=\lambda u & \text { in } U \\
> u=0 & \text { on } \partial U
> \end{array}\right.
> $$
> since $λ \notin \Sigma, u \equiv 0 \dots$

1. Why could the subsequence $ u_{k_j} $ converge in $L^2(U)$ and why it converges to $u$? (in \eqref{eq30})
2. Why could we take the limit in \eqref{eq30}?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving the [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) code. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: Thanks for your edit.

Comment: What is $\Sigma$?

Comment: $\Simga$ are the sets that the elliptic equation doesn't have a unique weak solution. You can see it in Evans.

Comment: @CameronWilliams in addition $\Sigma$ is called the real spectrum of the uniformly elliptic operator $L$. The above theorem is on page 324 of the second edition of Evan's PDEs book.

Comment: @CalvinKhor ah yeah thought so, but I'm used to $\sigma(T)$ notation from functional analysis.

Comment: @CameronWilliams so am I but Evans is ubiquitous :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The reason is stated in the appendix D4. Let me give slightly more detail. By Banach-Alaoglu, a bounded sequence in a Banach space has a subsequence that converges in the weak* topology. Since $H^1_0$ is a (separable) Hilbert space (in particular reflexive), this subsequence, considered as elements in the dual of $H^1_0$, converge in the weak topology. Regarding why convergence is equal to $u$, see 3 below.
2. This is guaranteed by the Rellich-Kondrachov compactness theorem(see previous chapter): $L^2(\Omega)$ is compactly embedded into $H^1_0(\Omega)$. So norm-boundedness in $H^1_0$ implies strong convergence of a subsequence in $L^2$.
3. You first take a subsequence $u_{k_i}$ of $u_k$ such that $u_{k_i}$ is weakly convergent in $H^1_0$ to *something*, call the limit $u$. Now you take a subsequence $v_j=u_{k_{i_j}}$ of $u_{k_i}$ such that $u_{k_{i_j}}$ converges to something in $L^2$, say it is $v$. In particular it converges weakly to $v$ in $L^2$. But $L^2$ is a subset of the dual of $H^1_0$. So by uniqueness of weak limits, $v=u$.